# Select distinct

Tags: mysql, query, select, distinct

I had some confusion regarding `distinct` keyword...

For example Table `test` has 5 columns `a` `b` `c` `d` `e`, and column `a` has repeated value, and I want to use `distinct` keyword to get distinct values while also fetching data from other columns

eg. `select distinct * from test` (I know the syntax is wrong here, I have written the query to help people get the idea of what I'm trying to do here)

Can someone help here?

///edit

```
ID  DEGREE  AWARDED ACADEMIC_PERIOD
147 GR           MS 2022
147 UG           BS 2020
170 GR           MA 2023
170 UG           BA 2018

Expected output is

ID  DEGREE  AWARDED ACADEMIC_PERIOD
147 GR           MS 2022
170 GR           MA 2023
```

found this data on dbastackexchange itself

Comment: Which record, from the records with multiple values for `a`, do you want in the final results? (It would be impossible to tell, when looking at this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/p0F8tAyB )

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: @Luuk, from column ```a```, I only want the distinct values, not anything else, while also getting the values from the other columns - eg ```select *``` or ```select distinct a , b, c, d```

Comment: @datascinalyst It would be best if you followed mustaccio's comment, and included some sample data and an example of the output you expect. What you're asking for is too ambiguous to describe with just words.

Comment: @J.D., sure, I'll add some data I actually found here on dbastackexchange.


I have edited it to the main question

Comment: @datascinalyst So you're not looking for the `DISTINCT` set of values, rather you want the latest row per `ID` in this case, it seems from your example?

Comment: @J.D., as per the tables I've included, there are 2 same ``ID's``. I want to get the distinct ``ID's``` with the remaining columns as well.

Comment: When looking at `ID=147` which value for `DEGREE` should be used? The MAX (=`UG`) of the MIN(`=GR`).  The same question for the other columns.  Based on the output you gave it is suggested you need the values that match the latest `ACEDEMIC_PERIOD`.

Comment: @Luuk and @J.D. I just used another method to get the answer! Tried ```group by```.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ID,
  DEGREE,
  AWARDED,
  ACADEMIC_PERIOD
FROM test
WHERE (ID, ACADEMIC_PERIOD) in (
  SELECT
   ID,
   MAX(ACADEMIC_PERIOD)
   FROM test
   GROUP BY ID);
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/llilmgO4)

The subquery selects the ID, and the needed/wanted ACADEMIC_PERIOD, so the correct records can be filtered.

EDIT: Another approach (same results)

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  DEGREE,
  AWARDED,
  ACADEMIC_PERIOD
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID,
    DEGREE,
    AWARDED,
    ACADEMIC_PERIOD,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ACADEMIC_PERIOD desc) as R
  FROM test) x
WHERE R=1
```

Comment: Thanks! This works.